# connect to aws port running neo4j

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I have installed neo4j on aws and its running fine .I have set tcp 7474 to my ip and ssh is working fine .Even http://aws_ip:7474/ is working fine and neo4j is connected .But when I try running neo4j script it keeps loading and displays time_out.Same code works with my local php(mamp/wamp) connected via my local:ip.
How can I access aws:port from my php,this php  is on separate cpanel/hotsing account which is not on aws . I really appreciate any help.
Also using :Amazon Linux AMI .Installed only neo4j. from here http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/how-deploy-neo4j-instance

Code:

```
<?php

$data2 ='CREATE (Person:Person {name:”test”}) RETURN Person';
$data2 = array("query" =>$data2);
$data_string = json_encode($data2);


$ch = curl_init('http://aws_ip:7474/db/data/cypher');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: can you provide the response from curl and also the content of your neo4j-server.properties file.

Comment: I dont get any response it keeps loading for 3-5 mins or so and then chrome displays time_out .Nothing happens also only difference in neo4j-server.properties file. is that I uncommented org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0 .Thats it.Just like the tutorial specifies: http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/how-deploy-neo4j-instance

Comment: did you try with a simple GET command like "curl aws_ip:7474" in the command line ?

Comment: I only tried the code above.Also what should I try to test connection?

Comment: well if a simple get request works the server is well configured so there is a problem with your curl options

Comment: if get does not work then ? Which I think is the problem

Comment: then there is a problem on the server / security policy / server setup